# How to transcribe large files in Google Speech API?

Tags: python, asynchronous, audio, google-speech-api, transcription

How would I transcribe a large file so that I avoid the error `Operation not complete and retry limit reached.` using Google Speech API asynchronous transcription for large audio files?

## Possible Solution

[If the operation has not completed, you can poll the endpoint by repeatedly making the GET request until the done property of the response is true.](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize#speech-async-recognize-gcs-protocol)

> Is this feasible to do so in python? or should I just break up the file into smaller files and retry?

## Known Issues with Speech API

- Encoding.

---

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR**

---

## Commands to Encode

```
ffmpeg -i 2017-06-13-17_48_51.flac -ac 1 mono.flac
```

## Why ffmpeg over sox?

> I chose ffmpeg because I got this error using sox

```
sox 2017-06-13-17_48_51.flac --channels=1 --bits=16 2017-06-13-17_48_51_more_stable.flac
```

> sox WARN dither: dither clipped 55 samples; decrease volume?

## Input Audio File

`Input File     : '2017-06-13-17_48_51.flac'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:21:18.40 = 61363200 samples ~ 95880 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 60.7M
Bit Rate       : 380k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit FLAC`

## Ran this command

```
ffmpeg -i 2017-06-13-17_48_51.flac -ac 1 mono.flac
```

## Output Audio File

`Input File     : 'mono.flac'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 48000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:21:18.40 = 61363200 samples ~ 95880 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 59.9M
Bit Rate       : 375k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit FLAC
Comment        : 'encoder=Lavf56.40.101'`

## Python File

> ## Google Speech API Asynchronous Ex. w/ Explicit Credentials
>
> > I changed Flac Hertz to "48000" and put in an explicit environment path
>
> ```
> import argparse
> import io
> import time
> import os
> os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "cloud_speech_service_keys.json"
> def transcribe_file(speech_file):
>     """Transcribe the given audio file asynchronously."""
>     from google.cloud import speech
>     speech_client = speech.Client()
>
>     with io.open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
>         content = audio_file.read()
>         audio_sample = speech_client.sample(
>             content,
>             source_uri=None,
>             encoding='LINEAR16',
>             sample_rate_hertz=16000)
>
>     operation = audio_sample.long_running_recognize('en-US')
>
>     retry_count = 100
>     while retry_count > 0 and not operation.complete:
>         retry_count -= 1
>         time.sleep(2)
>         operation.poll()
>
>     if not operation.complete:
>         print('Operation not complete and retry limit reached.')
>         return
>
>     alternatives = operation.results
>     for alternative in alternatives:
>         print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
>         print('Confidence: {}'.format(alternative.confidence))
>     # [END send_request]
> def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
>     """Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""
>     from google.cloud import speech
>     speech_client = speech.Client()
>
>     audio_sample = speech_client.sample(
>         content=None,
>         source_uri=gcs_uri,
>         encoding='FLAC',
>         sample_rate_hertz=48000)
>
>     operation = audio_sample.long_running_recognize('en-US')
>
>     retry_count = 100
>     while retry_count > 0 and not operation.complete:
>         retry_count -= 1
>         time.sleep(2)
>         operation.poll()
>
>     if not operation.complete:
>         print('Operation not complete and retry limit reached.')
>         return
>
>     alternatives = operation.results
>     for alternative in alternatives:
>         print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
>         print('Confidence: {}'.format(alternative.confidence))
>     # [END send_request_gcs]
>
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
>         description=__doc__,
>         formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
>     parser.add_argument(
>         'path', help='File or GCS path for audio file to be recognized')
>     args = parser.parse_args()
>     if args.path.startswith('gs://'):
>         transcribe_gcs(args.path)
>     else:
>         transcribe_file(args.path)
> ```